Why code executed in SynchronizationContext.Current.Send() not run in same thread in multiple calling

as the code shown in the picture, the id of CurrentThread is 1 in the first send(), but became to another value in the second send(),
Does that mean uiContext.Send() doesn't garantee that the code in callback is always excuted in the same thread?
Additionally, what should I do if I want my code being executed in UI thread after a calling to an async method.

nit: there's no point sending new CalcellationTokenSource().Token - since you've dropped the source on the floor, it will never become cancelled - maybe just pass default or CancellationTokenSource.None instead?

Send's only API-level guarantee is that it (Send) won't complete until the operation has been completed; how it does that, and which threads get used, is up to the specific implementation. You haven't told us what sync-context implementation you're using (although it seems to be UI related), so we can't say anything about any additional things specific to that implementation.
You mention "UI thread"; the UI may have features for thread switching, such as Control.Invoke on winforms.

it's just the default SynchronizationContext.Current in a winform application's UI thread.
And for 'UI thread', what if I don't create any Form or Control in this situation yet

@WCZ right, so mentioning winforms: would have helped ;p How winforms sync-context behaves if you haven't actually touched winforms yet ... hmm, that's a fun question and I honestly don't know the answer
